# How to find (or sort into sub-folder) multiple TIFF images with layers and/or transparency?

Tags: windows, macos, sorting, tiff, image-transparency

I have a folder with many TIFF files which I need to convert to JPEG. However some of the files have layers and/or transparency and these I don't want to convert.

So how can I move these TIFF files with layers and/or transparency into a sub-folder?

Answer (score 2):

According to my tests and [these](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html) [three](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/pagenumber.html) [pages](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/extrasamples.html), multi-layer or multi-page TIFFs have the *PageNumber* tag and transparent TIFFs have the *ExtraSamples* tag set to either **1** or **2**.

Once you know this it is easy to use [**ExifTool**](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to move both multi-page and transparent TIFFs into a separate directory:

```
exiftool -if "(($PageNumber) || ($ExtraSamples#>0))" -directory=Moved *.tif*
```

Comment: thanks, i will try it.
here is my solution for photoshop:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1851491

Comment: I *suspect* this will be orders-of-magnitude faster than the photoshop script.

Answer (score 0):

complete script solution for photoshop. make droplet and you are ready to go.

[complete script solution for photoshop](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1851491)